# STARTX in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04

I have installed ubuntu 11.04 Server - 64 bit edition & I want to further use it from GUI. Can any one guide me how to install GUI on top of it.

I get below message on command

```
The Prog startx is currently not installed. you can install it by typing: 
apt-get install xinit
```

I followed the mentioned instruction but got below message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information ... Done

E: Unable to locate package xinit
```

Pls suggest.. where to download xinit & how to deploy? Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

11.04 reached end of life on 10/28/2012.  That is why you are unable to install anything at this time.  I would suggest you install the newest version 14.04 which will be good through April 2019 or 12.04 which is supported through April 2017.  Also, you will need to install xorg once you have your server version installed.  You would also want to install a graphical desktop too.  [This page](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal) shows how to start with a server installation and get a lightweight desktop installed on top of it.  First though, you should install a supported version so you continue to get needed updates.

Comment: Good point.  Modified my post.